# Python: Calling function through while loop

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops, dictionary, while-loop

I'm trying to expand my program to a program that stores login details in a dictionary, and when you're trying to login in, it should ask for your username and password, and if the login details match the ones appended to the dictionary, it would say "You are logged in!", but I cannot seem to call my login() function at all, except the else print statement prints out when I have no login details entered but it doesn't loop back to the menu() like its supposed to, as I put it in a while loop. I think I kind of screwed up my while loops in the main routine but can't seem to get my head around it. Help would be appreciated.

```
store = {}

def menu(): 
    mode = input("""Hello, below are the modes that you can choose from:\n
    ##########################################################################
    a) Login with login details
    b) Register login details
    To select a mode, enter the corresponding letter of the mode below
    ##########################################################################\n
    > """).strip()
    return mode

def login():
    if len(store) > 0 : #user has to append usernames and passwords before it asks for login details
        print("Welcome to the login console")
        while True:
            username = input ("Enter Username: ") 
            if username == "":
                print("User Name Not entered, try again!")
                continue
            password = input ("Enter Password: ") 
            if password == "":
                print("Password Not entered, try again!")
                continue
            try:
                if store[username] == password:
                    print("Username matches!")
                    print("Password matches!")
                    logged() #jumps to logged function and tells the user they are logged on
                    break 
            except KeyError: #the except keyerror recognises the existence of the username and password in the list
                print("The entered username or password is not found!")

    else:
        print("You have no usernames and passwords stored!")

def register(): #example where the username is appended. Same applies for the password
    print("Please create a username and password into the password vault.\n")

    while True:
        validname = True
        while validname:
            username = input("Please enter a username you would like to add to the password vault. NOTE: Your username must be at least 3 characters long: ").strip().lower()
            if not username.isalnum():
                print("Your username cannot be null, contain spaces or contain symbols \n")
            elif len(username) < 3:
                print("Your username must be at least 3 characters long \n")
            elif len(username) > 30:
                print("Your username cannot be over 30 characters \n")
            else:
                validname = False 
        validpass = True

        while validpass:
            password = input("Please enter a password you would like to add to the password vault. NOTE: Your password must be at least 8 characters long: ").strip().lower()
            if not password.isalnum():
                print("Your password cannot be null, contain spaces or contain symbols \n")
            elif len(password) < 8:
                print("Your password must be at least 8 characters long \n")
            elif len(password) > 20:
                print("Your password cannot be over 20 characters long \n")
            else:
                validpass = False #The validpass has to be True to stay in the function, otherwise if it is false, it will execute another action, in this case the password is appended.
        store[username] = password
        validinput = True
        while validinput:
            exit = input("\nEnter 'end' to exit or any key to continue to add more username and passwords:\n> ")
            if exit in ["end", "End", "END"]:
                menu()
                break
            else:
                validinput = False
                register()
        return register

def logged():
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
    print("You are logged in!")


#Main routine

#The main program to run in a while loop for the program to keep on going back to the menu part of the program for more input till the user wants the program to stop
validintro = False 
while not validintro: 
        chosen_option = menu() #a custom variable is created that puts the menu function into the while loop
        validintro = True

        if chosen_option in ["a", "A"]:
            login()

        elif chosen_option in ["b", "B"]:
            register()

        else:
            print("""That was not a valid option, please try again:\n """)
            validintro = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because after printing "You have no usernames and passwords stored!", you return back to the outer while but never change validintro to false. This causes your while loop to end.

You should either return a value from login to know if there is no user and check that in the while, or from within the login function, in the else part set the global validintro to false(I would recommend the first way.)

Comment: Indeed. I think if you put the last line one level up (same as the if and elsif), you should be fine. But I think you should leave out the whole validintro thing. Just use While True, add a menu entry q to quit and add break if user selects q.